# How to do sequence labeling with an unlabeled dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have 1000 text files which have discharge summary for patients

SAMPLE_1

> The patient was admitted on 21/02/99. he appeared to have pneumonia at the time
>   of admission so we empirically covered him for community-acquired pneumonia with
>   ceftriaxone and azithromycin until day 2 when his blood cultures grew
>   out strep pneumoniae that was pan sensitive so we stopped the
>   ceftriaxone and completed a 5 day course of azithromycin. But on day 4
>   he developed diarrhea so we added flagyl to cover for c.diff, which
>   did come back positive on day 6 so he needs 3 more days of that…” this
>   can be summarized more concisely as follows: “Completed 5 day course
>   of azithromycin for pan sensitive strep pneumoniae pneumonia
>   complicated by c.diff colitis. Currently on day 7/10 of flagyl and
>   c.diff negative on 9/21.

SAMPLE_2

> The patient is an 56-year-old female with history of previous stroke; hypertension;
>   COPD, stable; renal carcinoma; presenting after
>   a fall and possible syncope.  While walking, she accidentally fell to
>   her knees and did hit her head on the ground, near her left eye.  Her
>   fall was not observed, but the patient does not profess any loss of
>   consciousness, recalling the entire event.  The patient does have a
>   history of previous falls, one of which resulted in a hip fracture. 
>   She has had physical therapy and recovered completely from that. 
>   Initial examination showed bruising around the left eye, normal lung
>   examination, normal heart examination, normal neurologic function with
>   a baseline decreased mobility of her left arm.  The patient was
>   admitted for evaluation of her fall and to rule out syncope and
>   possible stroke with her positive histories.

I also have a csv file which is 1000rows X 5columns. Each row has information entered manually for each of the text file.
So for example for the above two files, someone has manually entered these records in the csv file:

```
Sex, Primary Disease,Age, Date of admission,Other complications
M,Pneumonia, NA, 21/02/99, Diarhhea
F,(Hypertension,stroke), 56, NA, NA
```

My question is:

1. How do I represent use this information of text:labels to a machine learning algorithm
2. Do I need to do some manual labelling around the areas of interest in all the 1000 text files?

If yes then how and which method to use. (i.e. like `<ADMISSION> was admitted on 21/02/99</ADMISSION>`, 
    `<AGE>56-year-old</AGE>`)

So basically how do I use this text:labels data to automate the filling of labels.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask your teacher all this? You need to know what you're trying to do before you can ask for help on how to do it.

Comment: @alexis if only I had a teacher/mentor or could find it on internet. I know basic NLP, sentiment analysis on twitter etc, good practical hands on of regression & clustering. But this labeling thing Ive never done. Nor anyone in my group. Im not asking to spoonfeed but some relevant article, tutorial would help a ton !!

Comment: Machine learning labeling always has a goal -- what is yours? If you are trying to classify documents then you can probably just use this data as it is. If you are trying to extract concepts out of documents you will need more annotations. Help us help you :)

Comment: @AleksandarSavkov Lets say the sentence is "My age is 56 years" and for this sentence the csv file has In the Age column "56". Now in order to identify "age" from another sentence I need to train an algorithm with a training/labelled dataset. So my question is that give the sentences & their labels in csv file, how do I prepare a training/labelled dataset, something like "My age is <AGE>56</AGE> years". I dont know if this is the right way to label

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the algorithm that fills the gaps has not yet been invented. If the gaps were strongly correlated or had some sort of causality you might be able to model that with some sort of Bayesian model. Still with the amount of data you have this is pretty much impossible.

Now on the more practical side of things. You can take two approaches:

1. Treat the problem as a document-level task in which case you can just take all rows with a label and train on them and infer the labels/values of the rest. You should look at Naïve Bayes, Multi-class SVM, MaxEnt, etc. for the categorical columns and linear regression for predicting the numerical values.
2. Treat the problem as an information extraction task in which case you have to add the annotation you mentioned inside the text and train a sequence model. You should look at CRF, structured SVM, HMM, etc. Actually, you could look at some systems that adapt multiclass classifiers to sequence labeling tasks, e.g. SVMTool for POS tagging (can be adapted to most sequence labeling tasks).

Now about the problems, you will face. In `1.` it is very unlikely that you will predict the date of the record with any algorithm. It might be possible to roughly predict the patient age as this is something that usually correlates with diseases, etc. And it's very very unlikely that you will be able to even set up the disease column as an entity extraction task.

If I have to solve your problem I would probably pick approach `2.` which is imho the correct approach but could is also quite a bit of work. In that case, you will need to create markup annotations yourself. A good starting point is an annotation tool called [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/). Once you have your annotations, you could develop a classifier in the style of [CoNLL-2003](http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/ner/).

What you are trying to achieve seems quite a bit, especially with 1000 records. I think (depending on your data) you may be better off using ready products instead of building them yourself. There are open source and commercial products that might be able to use -- [lexigram.io](http://www.lexigram.io/) has an API, [MetaMap](https://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/) and [Apache cTAKES](http://ctakes.apache.org/downloads.cgi) are state-of-the-art open source tools for clinical entity extraction.

Comment: Lets say I have a list, which has record of disease for each of the text files. [(disease:"high BP"),(disease:"kidney problem")]. Now using this cant I label the first text which is
"Patient was suffering from high BP" as "Patient was suffering from <DISEASE>high BP</DISEASE>". I mean I just have to search for the value in text and if found wrap it with the key. Medical labelled corpus isnt available anywhere

Comment: I know it seems very simple but it isn't. What you are suggesting might work for some cases but even in your example if we need to look at real data it's very likely to fail. The medical term for high blood pressure is *hypertension* which should generally be in your disease column. The text, however, could very well contain *high BP*. That said, I don't know how your data was compiled, so it could be that this column was extracted from the text and it will work almost perfectly. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell the point is not to mark up the texts, but to extract the information represented by the annotations. This is an information extraction problem, and you should read up on techniques for this. The CSV file contains the information you want to extract (your "gold standard", so you should start by splitting it into training (90%) and testing (10%) subsets.

There is a named entity recognition task in there: Recognize diseases, numbers, dates and gender. You could use an off-the shelf chunker, or find an annotated medical corpus and use it to train one. You can also use a mix of approaches; spotting words that reveal gender is something you could hand-code pretty easily, for example. Once you have all these words, you need some more work, for example, to distinguish the primary disease from the symptoms; the age from other numbers, and the date of admission from any other dates. This is probably best done as a separate classification task.

I recommend you now read through the [nltk book](http://nltk.org/book), chapter by chapter, so that you have some idea of what the available techniques and tools are. It's the approach that matters, so don't get bogged down in comparisons of specific machine learning engines.

Comment: Lets say I have a list, which has record of disease for each of the text files. [(disease:"high BP"),(disease:"kidney problem")]. Now using this cant I label the first text which is
"Patient was suffering from high BP" as "Patient was suffering from <DISEASE>high BP</DISEASE>". I mean I just have to search for the value in text and if found wrap it with the key

Comment: a) only if the string is *exactly* the same as in the CSV file and does not occur in multiple places with different roles (e.g. admission date and date of a procedure). b)  Why would you want to do that? You haven't explained, and I doubt you actually need to.

Comment: thanks for replying. So Input is 1000 text files, output is a csv file with 5 columns & 1000 rows. A medical person read all the 1000 text files and populated the csv file. Now using the input and output we want to create a ML module which will automatically populate the csv file if those 5 fields are found in a new/unseen text. But to do this, Im assuming I need to tag these 5 values wherever present in all the 1000 files that I already have. This "tagged dataset+POS labeling+IOB tag" will then act as input features for the ML algorithm to train/learn. Let me know if made any sense.

Comment: I understand, and I'm telling you again, you don't *have* to do it the way you describe. Your goal is the CSV file, so you already have a corpus (text only) and the desired output. Treat it as an information extraction task, not as a text annotation task. If you try to annotate your current texts automatically, you will only introduce errors due to inevitable incorrect associations.